# Chrome Extension - Rerun extension script after redirecting current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a chrome extension which parses data from the current tab and post it to a url which does processing on the data. In certain cases the page may need to be redirected so that certain get parameters are present. My popup.js can successfully do the redirect, but I need to click on the extension a second time to get it to run properly. Note: it runs properly if the page has the correct parameters. How can I adjust this so that the code reruns after the redirect and posts the new source to the specified url.

Here is my popup.js:

```
var url = "";
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
  chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
    url = tabs[0].url;
    if (url.search("[?&]view=list") == -1)
    {
      url = setGetParameter(url,'view','list');
      chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id,{url:url});
      process(request);
    }
  });
  process(request);
});

function process(request) {
  if (request.action == "getSource") {
    message.innerText = request.source;
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('source',request.source);
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          message.innerText = xhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/scraper",true);
    xhttp.send(data);
  }  
}

function onWindowLoad() {

  var message = document.querySelector('#message');

  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "getPagesSource.js"
  }, function() {
    // If you try and inject into an extensions page or the webstore/NTP you'll get an error
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
      message.innerText = 'There was an error injecting script : \n' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message;
    }
  });

}

function setGetParameter(url, paramName, paramValue)
{
    var hash = location.hash;
    url = url.replace(hash, '');
    if (url.indexOf(paramName + "=") >= 0)
    {
        var prefix = url.substring(0, url.indexOf(paramName));
        var suffix = url.substring(url.indexOf(paramName));
        suffix = suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("=") + 1);
        suffix = (suffix.indexOf("&") >= 0) ? suffix.substring(suffix.indexOf("&")) : "";
        url = prefix + paramName + "=" + paramValue + suffix;
    }
    else
    {
    if (url.indexOf("?") < 0)
        url += "?" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    else
        url += "&" + paramName + "=" + paramValue;
    }
    return url + hash;
}

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [webRequest.onBeforeRedirect](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRedirect), this event fired when a redirect is about to be executed. You can listen to this event and do your logic again.

Don't forget to declare `webRequest` permission along with host permissions for any hosts whose network requests you want to access in you `manifest.json`.